# get a column containing the first non-nan value from a group of columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given data as:

```
|    |   a |   b |   c |
|---:|----:|----:|----:|
|  0 | nan | nan |   1 |
|  1 | nan |   2 | nan |
|  2 |   3 |   3 |   3 |
```

I would like to create some column `d` containing `[1, 2, 3]`

There can be an arbitrary amount of columns (though it's going to be <30).

Using

```
df.isna().apply(lambda x: x.idxmin(), axis=1)
```

Will give me:

```
0    c
1    b
2    a
dtype: object
```

Which seems useful, but I'm drawing a blank on how to access the columns with this, or whether there's a more suitable approach.

Repro:

```
import io
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(',a,b,c\n0,,,1\n1,,2,\n2,3,3,3\n'))
```

Comment: To reproduce the example I had to modify it `df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('a,b,c\n,,1\n,2,\n3,3,3\n'))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.fillna(method='bfill', axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Comment: This will work, I'm curious about whether there was an approach (sort of index match?) using what i had previously - but i think this will work with what i have thanks

Answer (score 1):

What if you use `min` on `axis = 1` ? :

```
df['min_val'] = df.min(axis=1)

     a    b    c  min_val
0  NaN  NaN  1.0      1.0
1  NaN  2.0  NaN      2.0
2  3.0  3.0  3.0      3.0
```

And to get the respective columns:

```
df['min_val_col'] = df.idxmin(axis=1)

     a    b    c min_val_col
0  NaN  NaN  1.0           c
1  NaN  2.0  NaN           b
2  3.0  3.0  3.0           a
```